# GCP MQL query: getting the traffic data of a kubernetes node

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, metrics, mql

I need to know the data traffic of one of my kubernetes nodes in a specific month.

This query gives me metrics for the last 30 days and the value is in MiB/s

```
fetch k8s_node
| metric 'kubernetes.io/node/network/received_bytes_count'
| align rate(30d)
| every 30d
| group_by ['node_name'],
    [value_received_bytes_count_aggregate:       aggregate(value.received_bytes_count)]
```

How can I get this value in bytes and specify a month(only February of 2023 for example)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code:

```
fetch k8s_node 
| metric 'kubernetes.io/node/network/received_bytes_count' 
| filter (time>=’2023-02-01T00:00:00Z’ and time<’2023-03-01T00:00:00Z’)
| align rate(1m) 
| every 1d 
| group_by ['node_name'], 
[value_received_bytes_count_aggregate: aggregate(value.received_bytes_count)]
```

By adding the filter clause we can limit the data only for the month February 2023. Check this [document for Date and Time Functions](https://dataschool.com/learn-sql/dates/)

Comment: filter  = (‘2023-02-01 00:00:00)
sum(‘value.received_bytes_count’)
here filter with Feb month and total amount of data received in Feb.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that worked.

```
fetch k8s_node
| metric 'kubernetes.io/node/network/received_bytes_count'
| filter resource.node_name =~ 'node_name.*'
| align delta(30d)
| every 30d
| group_by [], [value_received_bytes_count_aggregate: aggregate(value.received_bytes_count)]
```